# Filter data from extractor using other table

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to extract data from multiple files using csv custom extractor that uses a filter based on the content of other file.
Ex.
Files.txt content

```
file1
file4
```

Directories structure

```
/file1/file.txt
/file2/file.txt
/file3/file.txt
/file4/file.txt
```

I've extracted the Files.txt content to rowset @files and the files in directory to @filesDirectory rowset.

My problem is that if i join @filesDirectory with @files, no matter what files are in Files.txt, all files are read... I just want to read the files specified on it. 
But if i specify the file (without join the two rowset) it works!
Any help?

---

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @input string = @"/{dirname}/file.txt";
DECLARE @filterFile = @"/fileFilter.txt";
 @inputData =

        EXTRACT 
            dirname string,
            content string
        FROM @input
        USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '\n', quoting : false);

 @inputFilter =
        EXTRACT 
            directories string                
        FROM @filterFile
        USING Extractors.Text();

@result = SELECT * FROM @inputData AS id
            LEFT JOIN @inputFilter AS if ON (id.dirname = id.directories)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample script and code so we can reproduce this? Otherwise it is really hard to be of assistance. You did not post the logic of the custom extractor nor the u-sql scripts

Comment: Edited the first post. The problem is that all files are read. The filter not works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using a file list in your Extract expression? This cannot be a dynamic expression or parameter, so you'll have to generate the U-SQL script before each run based on the data in /input/files.txt, but this will avoid reading all of the files and filtering them on runtime.

```
DECLARE @input string = @"/{dirname}/file.txt";
DECLARE @filterFile = @"/fileFilter.txt";
@inputData =

    EXTRACT 
        dirname string,
        content string
    FROM "/file1/file.txt",
         "/file4/file.txt"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '\n', quoting : false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `INNER JOIN` and the U-SQL join syntax which is two equals signs (`==`) and this worked for me.  NB the files are still *read* but are filtered out of the results:

```
DECLARE @inputFile string = "/input/{dirName}/file.txt";

@input =
    EXTRACT dirName string,
            content string
    FROM @inputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv();


@inputFilter =
    EXTRACT directories string
    FROM "/input/files.txt"
    USING Extractors.Csv();


@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @input
         INNER JOIN
             @inputFilter
         ON dirName == directories
    WHERE dirName LIKE "file%";


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

My results with similar folder structure:

[image: My results]

Comment: I know that inner join works... My problem is that all files are loaded and is very inefficient when you just need few files... If you use "==" instead of INNER JOIN or IN clause using SQL.Array it works! You can test it and look at execution plan. The problem is that if the variable to compare is loaded from outside, all files will be loaded, and filtered after extract...